# From ListView to TextView (Parse)

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, parse-platform

With support, I have managed to retrieve list and images from parse, however, I want to be able to retrieve string that can be displayed in a textview as oppose to listview because there is no reason using a list when I am just retrieving one item. Furthermore, I have issues with the listview being scrollable on touch, so I guess it would be better if it was just a textview.

Below is the code that retrieves listview, I want to be able to display that information in a textview instead. In this case, I am trying to retrieve information from the ActivityName column of parse for the user that satisfies various conditions set.

```
ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();

        // query.whereEqualTo("ActivityName",userActivitySelectionName);

        query.whereNotEqualTo("objectId", ParseUser.getCurrentUser()
                .getObjectId());
        // users with Gender = currentUser.Looking_Gender
        query.whereEqualTo("Gender", userLookingGender);
        // users with Looking_Gender = currentUser.Gender
        query.whereEqualTo("Looking_Gender", userGender);
        query.setLimit(1);
        query.whereEqualTo("ActivityName", activityName);
        // query.whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("Age", minimumAge);
        // query.whereLessThanOrEqualTo("Age", maximumAge);
        query.orderByDescending("Name");

        Log.d(Constants.LOG, "");



        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {



            public void done(List<ParseUser> userlistactivityname, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < userlistactivityname.size(); i++) {
                        names.add(userlistactivityname.get(i).get("ActivityName").toString());
                    }
                    usersListActivityname = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(
                            R.id.userlistactivityname);
                    namesArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity()
                            .getApplicationContext(), R.layout.user_list_item,
                            names);
                    usersListActivityname.setScrollContainer(false);
                    usersListActivityname.setClickable(false);

                    usersListActivityname.setAdapter(namesArrayAdapter);



                } else {

                }
                }
            });
```

Below is the XML

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/userlistactivityname"
        android:layout_width="220dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView2"
        android:divider="@null" >
    </ListView>
```

Update:

```
 query2.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {



            public void done(List<ParseUser> userlistactivityname, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    TextView text=(TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.userlistactivityname);
                    text.get("ActivityName").setText();



                } else {

                }
                }
            });
```

XML

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/userlistactivityname"
        android:layout_width="220dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView2"
        android:divider="@null" >
    </TextView>
```

Update:
textview cannot be cast to android.widget.listview

```
query2.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {



            public void done(List<ParseUser> userlistactivityname, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                     for (int i = 0; i < userlistactivityname.size(); i++) {
                         mUserActivityNameRetrieved = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.userlistactivityname);


                         mUserActivityNameRetrieved.setText(userlistactivityname.get(i).get("ActivityName").toString());                     }


                } else {

                }
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

Just make your ListView a TextView, then when you databind the TextView in Java, called the .setText() method on the TextView.  Also, since you're setting the limit of your query to 1, you don't need to order your query.  The line `query.orderByDescending("Name");`is unnecessary

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. When applying your suggested changes, I have encountered a few issues like the text being displayed is not being generated from Parse.

Comment: @user3907211 - you are using the setText method incorrectly.  the setText method is a method of a TextView object, and the parameter it takes in is the text you want to set.  so your code should read text.setText(userlistactivityname.get(i).get("ActivityName").toString())

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response and support. I have added your suggestions, but have ran into an error while trying to run the application:          textview cannot be cast to android.widget.listview I have added the updated code under the update section of my initial post.